# TSM refusing to back up subdirectories on one partition but not others

Tags: backup

I'm having the problem where TSM refuses to recurse into subdirectories on my / partition. This does not apply to my other partitions, where it does recurse. This is independent of my include/exclude-list.

Here is the output from TSM:

```
# dsmc preview backup / -cons -subdir=yes
IBM Tivoli Storage Manager
Command Line Backup-Archive Client Interface
  Client Version 7, Release 1, Level 3.1 
  Client date/time: 25/01/16   18:29:49
(c) Copyright by IBM Corporation and other(s) 1990, 2015. All Rights Reserved.

Node Name: NODENAME.EXAMPLE.COM
Session established with server BLACKHOLE: Linux/x86_64
  Server Version 6, Release 3, Level 5.0
  Server date/time: 25/01/16   18:29:49  Last access: 25/01/16   18:28:47

Preview function invoked.
Depending on the number of objects to query, this operation could take a while to complete.

Are you sure you want to continue? (Yes (Y)/No (N)) y
Name:                                 Size:        Type:        Status:    Pattern:               Source:          Mgmt Class:
-----                                 -----        -----        -------    --------               -------          -----------
/lib                                  5  B         -            Included   -                      -                DEFAULT
/foo                                  0  B         -            Included   -                      -                DEFAULT
Preview output has been successfully written to file 'dsmprev.txt'.
```

And this is what my root partition actually looks like (the file foo is there for debugging)

```
# ls -l /
total 25
drwxr-xr-x   1 root root 1066 Jan 23 13:04 bin
drwxr-xr-x   6 root root 4096 Jan  6 12:45 boot
drwxr-xr-x  22 root root 4620 Jan 25 18:06 dev
drwxr-xr-x   1 root root 5626 Jan 25 15:04 etc
-rw-r--r--   1 root root    0 Jan 25 18:29 foo
drwxr-xr-x   1 root root  100 Nov  4 15:52 home
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root    5 Oct 20 16:09 lib -> lib64
drwxr-xr-x   1 root root 1410 Oct 20 16:09 lib32
drwxr-xr-x   1 root root 4880 Jan 25 09:50 lib64
drwxr-xr-x   1 root root   10 Oct 24 22:17 media
drwxr-xr-x   1 root root   10 Oct 31  2013 mnt
drwxr-xr-x   1 root root  348 Jan 24 17:12 opt
dr-xr-xr-x 388 root root    0 Jan 25 08:55 proc
drwx------   1 root root  512 Jan 25 18:26 root
drwxr-xr-x  26 root root  680 Jan 25 18:06 run
drwxr-xr-x   1 root root 4060 Jan 25 09:50 sbin
drwxr-xr-x   1 root root    0 May 27  2015 srv
dr-xr-xr-x  12 root root    0 Jan 25 18:29 sys
drwxrwxrwt  18 root root 1500 Jan 25 18:26 tmp
drwxr-xr-x   1 root root  194 Nov 15 14:11 usr
drwxr-xr-x   1 root root  186 May 31  2015 var
```

The / file system is on btrfs, with no subvolumes (at the moment).

Here is the contents of my dsm.sys file (mostly standard):

```
SErvername  BLACKHOLE
   COMMMethod         TCPip
   TCPPort            1542
   SSL YES
   TCPServeraddress   blackhole.example.com
   NODENAME nodename.example.com

         PasswordDir "/etc/tivoli/"
         PasswordAccess generate
         ErrorLogName "/var/log/tsm/dsmerror.log"
         SchedLogName "/var/log/tsm/dsmsched.log"
   inclexcl /etc/tivoli/incl-excl-file
```

The inclexcl file is currently empty (but it still fails with my regular file, that works fine on other computers).

Comment: I don't remember TSM well enough, but my first theory is that having an *empty* incl/excl file may be causing the client to exclude everything ("don't include anything"); what happens if you remove the inclexcl config from dsm.sys?

Comment: @JeffSchaller Thanks for the suggestion! I should probably have mentioned that the inclexcl-file is empty right now for debugging. It also doesn't work with my regular file (that works on other computers). And, just for completeness, I just tested it without any inclexcl line, with the same result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is caused by a bug in the version of TSM that is used, where the TSM client can silently skip files on btrfs file systems and bind mounts.

Details of the bug can be found on the IBM website:
http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21977589

The solution is to upgrade to a newer version of the TSM client (like 7.1.4.1).